# Dict update every pair of values for some reason, how to work only with one?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a code for adding items from series to dict,
my dict:

```
{'type': [], 'geometry.type': [], 'geometry.coordinates': [], 'properties.id': [], 'properties.nl': [], 'properties.nl_en': [], 'properties.verticalDistance': []}
```

I assumed that this code will add new items in lists according to it`s key:

```
data = dict.fromkeys(columns, [])
for key, frame in df: 
    for col in columns:
        data[col].append(pd.Series.tolist(frame[col]))
```

but it adds new values in each pair in dict, while I need it to work like

```
if col == 'type':
     {'type': [new value], 'geometry.type': [],...}
if col == 'geometry.type':
     {'type': [...], 'geometry.type': [geometry.type],...}
```

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvGd0.png)

Or with more details:

```
data = dict.fromkeys(columns, [])
print(data)
for key, frame in df: 
    for field in columns:
        a = pd.Series.tolist(frame[field])[0]
        data[field].append(a)
        print(a)
        print(field)
        print(data)
```

And result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNu9G.png):
So at first seems like everything is good, but still all elements are updated and I cant understand why

Comment: this looks like a geojson format, are you using geopandas and shapely ?

Comment: what is your question which is your actual output which is your expected output?